# Add walk animation. I just want to have the sprite image change when i hold down the key, like shuffle between 3 different walking images.

Tags: python

> This is my first post and i have no idea what i am doing hah, but i started learning pygame tonight
>       and i want to know to add a walk animation. I just want to variable "walk" to change images every .5 or so seconds of holding the
>   key down

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
#imports pygame and initializes the module
pygameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
#creates a screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake(;")
gameExit = False


walk = pygame.image.load("pokemon walk sprite sheet.png")
walkx = 350
walky = 330
walkx_change = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()




while not gameExit:
    pygameDisplay.blit(walk,(walkx,walky))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                walkx_change = -10
                walk = pygame.image.load("walk sheet left.png")
               #right here i want code to make it switch to another image after .5 or so seconds

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                walkx_change = 10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                walkx_change = 0



    walkx += walkx_change


    pygameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do animation like that. You have to create a class with `Sprite` module first. And you have to import every image(frame) of your animation.

```
class Asker(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, konum):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.resimler = [pygame.image.load("01.png"), pygame.image.load("02.png"),pygame.image.load("03.png"),pygame.image.load("04.png"),pygame.image.load("05.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("06.png"),pygame.image.load("07.png"),pygame.image.load("08.png"),pygame.image.load("09.png"),pygame.image.load("10.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("11.png"),pygame.image.load("12.png"),pygame.image.load("13.png"),pygame.image.load("14.png"),pygame.image.load("15.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("16.png")]
        self.image = self.resimler[0]
        self.rect =  self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = konum
        self.say = 0
```

It's an example from my script, see I load 16 pictures, you have to split them first with [**gimp**](http://www.gimp.org/) or `photoshop`.That pictures I splitted them from an animation. Then you have to rotate them etc etc. You should check some tutorials of `Sprite`, before it, learn basic Pygame.

Comment: Okay cool.. so how would i do that in my program? load all the sprites required for the animation and then what? and how do i implement this all in the KEYDOWN: statement? thank you for your help!

Comment: You want a Sprite lesson here, it's not possible. As I said you should check tutorials on the web.

Comment: @B.Morris You're welcome, if it's solved your question check it as answer please

Comment: @B.Morris https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5F-aGDIYaM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq&index=1 check these tutorials, it's pretty awesome

Comment: are there tutorials over classes and animation in that series? and will do!